# Sitecore Workbox make Comment Textbox Required

Tags: sitecore

In sitecore workbox for some actions we can allow the user to type some comments by turning off the "Supress message" property. Is it possible to make them required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a blog post about making the comment for **Reject** command obligatory. You should be able to adapt this solution to your needs easily:

[**sitecore** workflows - mandatory comment for reject command](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/sitecore-workflows-mandatory-comment-for-reject-command/)